# How to create a view Based on dataBase Fields in asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3

i have table called as Support, which have a field named Name and contains data namely SE,DSE

i have created a View for SE and DSE respectively, now my requirement is that in future suppose one more Support name is added then i have to manually create one more View Column for that particular Support Name. so i want that the support Name column should be automatically generated when there are some support name added in the table in future..

please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use MVC scaffolding.  Taking your model as an example, if you put this in your View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Support>
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model);
}
grid.GetHtml();
```

Then the output will display all the columns in your table.  If you update the model later, columns in the Webgrid get updated automatically.

Comment: please help with some example